# IIS 7.5 serving up blank pages (static AND dynamic content)

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, iis-7.5

Until today IIS 7.5 has been serving up pages with no problems at all. This morning I try to access one of my sites through localhost, but I get a completely blank page back. No errors, just empty html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML><HEAD>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" 
content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"></HEAD>
<BODY></BODY></HTML>
```

The IIS logs show the following for every request:

```
2014-04-02 10:30:18 127.0.0.1 GET /LeadService/LeadService.asmx - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+
(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko 200 0 0 9360
```

The problem occurs when I try to access dynamically generated  content (aspx, asmx) or static content (html+js).
If I try to telnet to localhost on port 80, I instantly get the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Wed, 02 Apr 2014 18:21:57 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 326

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Verb</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request verb is invalid.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

I have not installed any new software and the only thing running on port 80 is IIS.

One thing I have just discovered, if I open IIS Manager and go into the Basic Settings of one of my web apps, if I click "Test Settings" then I get an "Invalid Application Path" error. I have checked permissions on the folders, the App Pool that the app is running under and that the path is actually valid.

Comment: So what has changed? Try to use another computer, different browsers or different versions of the same browser. IIS logged 200 OK so to IIS it seems like everything is working.

Comment: I don't know what has changed. IIS was working fine, I shut my laptop lid, open it the following morning - no sites, just blank pages. If I try a non-existent site, I don't get a 404 error, I get the same blank page. The problem is the same in Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer. I only have one computer.

Comment: Also, when requesting a non-existent site, the IIS log also reports a 200 OK entry.

Comment: When you create new application does it work or IIS gives you also blank page? Also when you enable directory browsing what does it show you?

Comment: Directory browsing also gives a blank page. New sites / applications -> blank page. I have run ProcessMonitor against the w3wp process, and I get a Path Not Found error when running an ASP .Net site: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LeadService\leadservice.asmx\web.config, but I don't know why its appending the web.config to the end of the asmx file???

Comment: And when you access some static .html does it also append web.config?

Comment: Maybe some rewrite rule? Check web.config in every application including root web site if there is something strange.

Answer (score 2):

Generally you need to add `Static Content` in your `Windows Features` (`Control Panel/Program and Features`, click on `Turn Windows features on and off`) under `Internet Information Services/World Wide Web Services/Common HTTP Features`

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with Static Compression under URL Rewrite or Under compression you have 2 Options in IIS.

1. DoStaticCompression
2. DoDynamicCompression

Set the DoStaticCompression to False. 
I know this will result in performance to be slow. I'm facing the same issue. unchecking the same resolves it for now.